# Writing a parser with multiple expected completions

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic

Let's say I have the following grammar for boolean queries:

```
 Query     := <Atom> [ <And-Chain> | <Or-Chain> ]
 Atom      := "(" <Query> ")" | <Var> <Op> <Var> 
 And-Chain := "&&" <Atom> [ <And-Chain> ]
 Or-Chain  := "||" <Atom> [ <Or-Chain> ] 
 Var       := "A" | "B" | "C" | ... | "Z"
 Op        := "<" | ">" | "="
```

A parser for this grammar would have the pseudo-code:

```
 parse(query) :=
   tokens <- tokenize(query)
   parse-query(tokens)
   assert-empty(tokens)

 parse-query(tokens) :=
   parse-atom(tokens)
   if peek(tokens) equals "&&" 
     parse-chain(tokens, "&&")
   else if peek(tokens) equals "||"
     parse-chain(tokens, "||")

 parse-atom(tokens) :=
   if peek(tokens) equals "("
     assert-equal( "(", shift(tokens) )
     parse-query(tokens)
     assert-equal( ")", shift(tokens) )
   else
     parse-var(tokens)
     parse-op(tokens)
     parse-var(tokens)

 parse-chain(tokens, connector) :=
   assert-equal( connector, shift(tokens) )
   parse-atom(tokens)
   if peek(tokens) equals connector
      parse-chain(tokens, connector)

 parse-var(tokens) :=
   assert-matches( /[A-Z]/, shift(tokens) )

 parse-op(tokens) :=
   assert-matches( /[<>=]/, shift(tokens) )
```

What I want to make sure of, though, is that my parser will report helpful parse errors.  For example, given a query that starts with `"( A < B && B < C || ..."`, I'd like an error like :

```
found "||" but expected "&&" or ")"
```

The trick with this is that it gathers expectations from across different parts of the parser.  I can work out ways to do this, but it all ends up feeling a little clunky.

Like, in Java, I might throw a `GreedyError` when attempting to peek for a "&&" or "||"

```
// in parseAtom
if ( tokens.peek() == "(" ) {
    assertEqual( "(", tokens.shift() );
    try {
        parseQuery(tokens);
        caught = null;
    }
    catch (GreedyError e) {
        caught = e;
    }
    try { 
        assertEqual( ")", tokens.shift() );
    }
    catch (AssertionError e) {
        throw e.or(caught);
    }
}
// ...
// in parseChain
assertEqual( connector, tokens.shift() );
parseAtom(tokens);
if (tokens.peek() == connector) {
    parseChain(tokens, connector);
}
else {
    new GreedyError(connector);
}
```

Or, in Haskell, I might use `WriterT` to keep track of my last failing comparisons for the current token, using `censor` to clear out after every successful token match.

But both of these solutions feel a bit hacked and clunky.  I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, some pattern, that could handle this elegantly.  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an L(AL)R(1) state machine.  More details about LALR can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser_generator).

What you want to use for error reporting is the FIRSTOF set for dot in each state.  This answer will make sense when you understand how the parser states are generated.

If you *have* such a set of states, you can record the union of the FIRSTOF sets with each state; then when in that state, and no transition is possible, your error message is "Exepect (firstof currentstate)".

If you don't want to record the FIRST sets, you can easily write an algorithm that will climb through the state tables to reconstruct it.   That would the algorithmic equivalent of your "peeking ahead".